# How do I query an Alexa device for a parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a custom skill that will query a custom device for a parameter. In this case, it is the voltage.

The device is a node on node red so it is not a physical device but a virtual one.

The device will be linked to my account. Here is what I am thinking that the workflow would be:

1. Hello alexa ask test app what is the motor voltage?
2. I get a session request that goes to my custom intent and executes the corresponding function on the lambda server
   ----- here is the part that is fuzzy ----
3. Using some device ID, the lambda server sends out a request to the virtual device
4. The node for the device gets this request (mostly likely some sort of JSON object), parses it and sends back out the requested parameter that is stored on the Node Red server (For the sake of the discussion lets say that it is a constant number that is on the server)
5. Lambda server gets this response and forwards it to the Alexa service
6. Alexa - The voltage of the motor is twelve volts

So basically, how do I do this? Is this the correct workflow for Alexa or is there a different workflow? What components (besides the components needed for Alexa to run) will I be needing? I believe that I can get the ID of the device in the handler_interface.